# eigenstate of a system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

> There exists a physical operator F whose eigenvalues are a or b. Normalised eigenstate is A and B for each. The average value of F was f when measured from a certain system. Describe the eigenstate of this system in terms of A and B.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just a physics student so I could be wrong, just trying to help you: using Dirac bracket notation you can write your system state $ |psi \rangle $
as a superposition of the eigenstates, with complex coeficients α and β,
$$| \psi \rangle =\alpha |a\rangle + \beta |b\rangle, $$
and you can write the expected value as:
$$\langle \psi | \hat F | \psi \rangle =f.$$
Knowing that $\hat F |a\rangle =a|a\rangle,\ \hat F |b\rangle =b|b\rangle$ I think that you should be able to finish.